# backbone extend and calling functions

Tags: backbone.js

I think I'm misunderstanding some scoping issues. 
I am running the TODO backbone app and after the "new app.AppView();"

I am trying this:
app.AppView.render()

as well as other functions that I thought were being extended, but they seem unavailable.

The second question is ..Why does chrome developer tools say "child" next to TODORouter and Todos

EDIT
The todo link
[TODO](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/)

This is the code I'm mostly reffering to

```
$(function() {

    // Kick things off by creating the **App**.
    new app.AppView();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Save off your new appview in a var and then use it from there.

```
var myAppView = new app.AppView();
// ...
myAppView.render();
```

Comment: Works, great , why? I'm sure this is basic js that I have no clue about. If these Objects are still available after the initial load, then why are the extended functions not available? And the second question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have scoping issues, but kind of 'coping with javascript' -issues.

at `app.AppView` is stored a `Function` -object named `AppView`. In javascript functions are used as 'classes' (don't think about Java classes!) in a system called prototype inheritance. Don't get mixed into that yet.

When you call

```
new app.AppView()
```

you create a new `instance` of this `AppView` 'class', that IS an object. So when you call

```
app.AppView.render()
```

you're trying to call the function render of the 'class' (or class-but-not-quite-a-class). Now that isn't right one bit.

So (like in Java or any other oo-language), you have to store the instance you get by calling the constructor to a variable.

```
var appView = new app.AppView();
```

Now that you have an instance, you can do whatever you like with it

```
appView.render();
```

Comment: Getting there....but the stock TODO code doesnt create a named instance of AppView, so how does it have access to this (new app.AppView()) view AFTER everything is rendered?

Comment: maybe you should post a link to this todo tutorial